# Non-scientific word for "Saturation point"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that describes the phenomenon that happens when something collects up to the point that it precipitates an event?  If "saturation point" is in sufficient common usage, that would be nice too.  (Not even sure that "precipitates" is in common usage here)

For example:

> In all of these books, the unity the characters experience is muddled by factions which swell and waver until they reach the ______ and precipitate a catastrophe.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps the word "factor" (a circumstance, fact, or influence that contributes to a result or outcome) is intended rather than "faction" (a small, organized, dissenting group within a larger one, especially in politics)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that my usage was unconventional!  I meant "factions" as in the development of competitive groups, not small groups within a bigger one.

Comment: In that case your usage is perfectly valid.  Lacking a broader context, I made an assumption which was, in fact, invalid.  Since you're talking about groups of people rather than circumstances, factions it is!

Comment: Saturation refers to the maximum capacity of some A to contain something else B which somehow permeates A: B flows through A, or is dissolved in A, or dispersed in A, or absorbed into A.   A sponge can be saturated with water if it can't soak up any more. A section of highway can be saturated with traffic. A semiconductor can be saturated with electric current, having no more free carriers. When a solvent is saturated with solute, we get precipitation. When air is saturated with  moisture we get condensation (mist, fog, rain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a single word, but how about **critical mass**?

> "In all of these books, the unity the characters experience is muddled
>   by factions which swell and waver until they reach a **critical mass**
>   and precipitate a catastrophe.

From Dictionary.com:

> **critical mass**: an amount necessary or sufficient to have a significant effect or to achieve a result: *a critical mass of popular
>   support*.

Comment: Both *tipping point* and *critical mass* are grossly overused, so much so that I suspect that anyone who uses either in ordinary speech does not know what they mean (or worse). What's wrong with *saturation point* ? It's not an obscure scientific term.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Two reasons: (1) The OP explicitly asked for an alternative to *saturation point*, and (2) *saturation point* may not work as well in the OP's example as *tipping point*, *critical mass*, or some other word or phrase. I don't disagree that *saturation* point has a non-scientific meaning (according to Dictionary.com, it is a point at which some capacity is at its fullest; limit: *After a while she reached the saturation point and could absorb nothing more from the lectures*), but I'm not sure it's better understood in ordinary speech than either of the suggested alternatives.

Comment: I ended up using the word critical mass because I thought it most represented my idea of passing a threshold by gaining "mass."

Comment: @HanryHu Thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated. It also conjures the images of all hell breaking loose, a chain reaction, loss of control, catastrophe.

Answer (score 9):

It's not a single word, but *[tipping point](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tipping-point?q=tipping%20point)* is a common expression for "the point at which a series of small changes or incidents becomes significant enough to cause a larger, more important change".

Answer (score 0):

Capacity 
Limit 
Threshold (for)

Perhaps precipitate should be result in or lead to or culminate in. Are you trying to convey a cause and effect relationship?